# Проблема с кластеризацией при масштабировании в Яндекс картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Не могу понять, почему при увеличении/уменьшении масштаба на карте остаются только кластеризованные метки. При увеличении на кластеризованной метке, кластер распадается и метки тут же исчезают.
Кто подскажет в чем дело?

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [49.338848, 12.861112],
            zoom: 2.5
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#orangeDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#orangeClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/js/data.json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
        //myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
    });

}
```

Ссылка на JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MaksimZykov/8frc4ph6/
Там все работает. Есть подозрение, что я подсовываю неправильный JSON-файл.
К сожалению еще не разобрался как ссылаться на локальные файлы в JSFiddle. Содержимое JSON файла пока выложу сюда:

```js
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    59.939095,
                    30.315868
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    43.115536,
                    131.885485
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    54.70739,
                    20.507307
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    55.713557,
                    84.933869
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    52.286387,
                    104.28066
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    52.286387,
                    104.28066
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Если вы добавите ссылку на пример, например на jsfiddle то помочь будет легче. У меня не воспроизводится https://jsfiddle.net/4z7gnbwc/ Но пальцем в небо могу сказать, что скорее всего одна или несколько координат меток, которые вы добавляете с неправильными координатами: пустыми, заданными строкой или т.п.

Comment: @se0ga, обновил инфу в вопросе. Может будут какие мысли?

Comment: Вы проверили, что все координаты правильные? Вот так можно подсунуть данные https://jsfiddle.net/oshcvf94/

Comment: Удалось решить проблему?